# edit only the 1st column of a fasta header by removing strings after '-'

Tags: awk, sed, fasta

I have a fasta file with the following header structure:

```
>Saurogobio_punctatus-NC_080528.1|taxid=1771284|cellularorganisms,Eukaryota,Opisthokonta,Metazoa
GCTAGCGTAGCTTAATATAAAGCATAACACTGAAGATGTTAAGATGAGCCCTAA
```

Where each section is separated by a pipe `'|'`, and the first section is a combination of `species_name-accessionID`.

I want to remove the accesionIDs after the hyphen `'-'`, but keep everything else. Like this:

```
>Saurogobio_punctatus|taxid=1771284|cellularorganisms,Eukaryota,Opisthokonta,Metazoa
GCTAGCGTAGCTTAATATAAAGCATAACACTGAAGATGTTAAGATGAGCCCTAA
```

I've tried:

```
sed -E '/^>/s/(\|[^-]*)-.*$/\1/' input.fasta > output.fasta
```

But this removes everything after the hyphen `'-'`:

```
>Saurogobio_punctatus
GCTAGCGTAGCTTAATATAAAGCATAACACTGAAGATGTTAAGATGAGCCCTAA
```

I've used this piece of code before to edit my header and include the `taxid=` before my 2nd column:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } /^>/ { print $1, "taxid=", $2, $3; next } { print }' file.fa > edit_file
```

I was wondering if there is a way to maybe combine these 2 commands, where i edit my first column and then reprint the rest, but i don't know how to do it :(

I appreciate any help with this!

Comment: `sed -E 's/^(>[^-|]*)(-[^|]*)/\1/' file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest with `sed`:

```
sed 's/-[^|]*//' file
```

Output to stdout:

```
>Saurogobio_punctatus|taxid=1771284|cellularorganisms,Eukaryota,Opisthokonta,Metazoa
GCTAGCGTAGCTTAATATAAAGCATAACACTGAAGATGTTAAGATGAGCCCTAA
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: If there is no `|` after `-` then this removes everything after `-`.

Comment: Oops... sorry! I deleted my old comment instead of editing. But you're right! I used a different version of my file that was not formatted like that and that's why it didn't work. But now I can see it works! Again, thanks for the FAQ :D

Answer (score 2):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
/^>/  { n=index($1,"-"); $1=substr($1,1,n-1) }
1
' input.fasta
```

This generates:

```
>Saurogobio_punctatus|taxid=1771284|cellularorganisms,Eukaryota,Opisthokonta,Metazoa
GCTAGCGTAGCTTAATATAAAGCATAACACTGAAGATGTTAAGATGAGCCCTAA
```

Answer (score 2):

Another potential awk option:

```
awk '/>/ {gsub("-[^\\|]*\\|", "|", $0); print} !/>/ {print}' input
>Saurogobio_punctatus|taxid=1771284|cellularorganisms,Eukaryota,Opisthokonta,Metazoa
GCTAGCGTAGCTTAATATAAAGCATAACACTGAAGATGTTAAGATGAGCCCTAA
```

Or, a better option, using bioinformatics software designed for the task (https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/):

```
seqkit replace -p "\-[^|]*|" -r "" input
>Saurogobio_punctatus|taxid=1771284|cellularorganisms,Eukaryota,Opisthokonta,Metazoa
GCTAGCGTAGCTTAATATAAAGCATAACACTGAAGATGTTAAGATGAGCCCTAA
```